# which javascript IDE automatically parse include js file in HTML code?

Tags: javascript

I'm using Aptana plugin for eclipse, but it doesn't parse included js file when I write js code in a HTML file.Is Aptana support this function? If not Could you please show me which javascript IDE automatically parse include js file in HTML code? Thanks for help.

Comment: if possible, you should avoid writing JavaScript inside HTML. Trust me, it will come back and haunt you. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RubyMine, WebStorm, PhpStorm and IntelliJ IDEA from [JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/) all do this.

Comment: is there any configure in Aptana also do this?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't used Aptana for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver CS5 do this.